The continuity of $(Af)(x)=\int^x_0 \frac{f(t)}{x} dt$

Linear operator is given in $L_2[0,1]$:
$D(A) = C[0,1] \subset L_2[0,1]$
$A:D(A)\rightarrow L_2[0,1]$
given by    $   (Af)(x) = \int^x_0 \frac{f(t)}{x} dt$,  $x\in(0,1]$
Show that A is a continuous operator.

Clearly $||A||^2 \leq \sup_{||f||_2 = 1} \int^1_0 \frac{1}{x^2}(\int^x_0 |f(t)|dt)^2 dx$
I tried both Hölder's inequality and splitting the integral into a sum of integrals over $(0, \delta)$ and $(\delta, 1)$, but I didn't come up with the correct estimate.
Can you help me, I'm really stuck.

@SineoftheTime as Mark writes $C[0,1]\subset L_2[0,1]$, I think it's fair to assume both spaces are given the $L^2$-norm

Please add your thoughts/attempts to the question. Read here "How to ask a good question":https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992

Could you include what estimates you've tried, since you write that you've failed in your attempts at that?

Generally, $C[0,1]$ means the $\sup$ norm. Please clarify.

@ copper.hat, you are absolutely right, I made a mistake when typing it. It should be correct now.

It is still unclear what norm you intend to have on the domain.

The close brigade is out again.

I usually belong to the (useful) "close brigade" but I am discovering this post and after some hesitation, voted to reopen it, because there seems to be enough context. In particular, the norm on the domain is clear from "given in $L_2[0,1]$" and "$
:||A||^2 \leq \sup_{\color{red}{||f||_2} = 1}\int^1_0 \frac{1}{x^2}(\int^x_0 |f(t)|dt)^2 dx$".

This solution may be treated as an overkill, but I couldn't find a simpler argument.
It is easy to see that $A$ is a bounded operator from  $L^\infty(0,1)$ to itself, as
$|(Af)(x)|\le \|f\|_\infty,$ thus $\|Af\|_\infty\le \|f\|_\infty.$ On the other hand  $A$ is unbounded as an operator from $L^1(0,1)$ to $L^1(0,1)$  because
$$ (A{\bf 1}_{[0,a]})(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & 0< x\le a\\ {a\over x} & a\le x\le 1\end{cases} $$ hence $$\|A{\bf 1}_{[0,a]}\|_1=a-a\log a\ge -a\log a=(-\log a) \|{\bf 1}_{[0,a]}\|_1$$ However $A$ is an operator of weak type $(1,1),$ which by definition means that there is $c>0$ satisfying
$$\sup_{\delta>0}\delta\, m\{x\,:\, |(Af)(x)|\ge \delta\}\le c\|f\|_1$$ where $m(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.
In our case  we have $|(Af)(x)|\le \|f\|_1/x.$ Thus
$$\{x\,:\, |(Af)(x)|\ge \delta\}\subset (0, \|f\|_1/\delta] $$
Hence $$\delta \,m\{x\,:\, |(Af)(x)|\ge \delta\}\le \|f\|_1$$
By the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem $A$ is bounded from $L^p(0,1)$ to itself for any $p>1.$
Remark Perhaps it is possible to find a direct way for $p=2$ by mimicking the proof of the Marcinkiewicz theorem.

Clearly $|(Af)(x)|\leq \|f\|_\infty$ for every $x\in (0,1]$.
Then $A:C[0,1]\to L_\infty(0,1)$ is continuous, and the natural map $L_\infty(0,1)\to L_2(0,1)$ is also continuous.

I believe OP wants the norm on $C[0,1]$ to be the $L^2$-norm
